# How to convert List<AnonymousType> to List<string>

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0, casting, anonymous-types

I want to convert a `List<AnonymousType>` to `List<string>`. I have the following code:

```
var lkpiTodisplay = _MGMTDashboardDB.KPIs.Where(m => m.Compulsory == true && m.Active == true)
                                         .Select(m => new
                                         {
                                             KPI_Name = m.Absolute == true ? m.KPI_Name : (m.KPI_Name + "%")
                                         }).ToList();

for(int i=1; i<= BusinessTargetCol; i++)
{
   lkpiTodisplay.Add(new
   {
      KPI_Name = "Business Target"
   });
}
```

This code creates a `List<AnonymousType>`. Then I would like to assign this List to a variable `List<string>`, as shown in the following code:

```
DashboardViewModel lYTMDashboard = new DashboardViewModel()
{
      KPIList = (List<string>) lkpiTodisplay,
      //other assignments
};
```

The casting does not work. How can I convert the variable? Other solutions that modify the first code snippet are welcome, as long as the **KPIList** variable is kept as a `List<string>`.

Thanks

Francesco

Comment: Never use `== true`, it's a waste.

Comment: Doesn't look like you need to create the anonymous class in the first place, so don't.

Comment: @minitech: interesting argument. It is a waste in term of performance?

Comment: A slight one (two CPU operations, a few nanoseconds maybe) but it just makes your code file bigger (and less readable, sometimes, because it can make scrollbars appear).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can skip the Anonymous Class if you can and if you have no need for it

```
 lkpiTodisplay.Add("Business Target");
```

or

you can do

```
lkpiTodisplay.Select( x => x.KPI_Name).ToList();
```

to get `List<String>`

Comment: the second solution is what I was looking for. It was so simple I didn't even think about it! Many thanks

Answer (score 6):

You cannot assign List<AnonymousType> to List<String>, that types are not compatible.
Use `lkpiToDiplay.Select(i => i.ToString()).ToList()`